# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO), but data delivered

Tags: php, mysql

On my Desktop everything's fine, but on the server I get this warning, and then the data is delivered(!) (using the correct password)

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using 
>   password: NO) in /home/www/web512/html/include/db_ajax.php on line 7

If I change the password the warning changes to "password: YES", but I can't of course login either...

```
    <?php   
    include 'connect.php';

    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf-8');
    $jahr = $_POST["year"];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM termine ORDER BY datum DESC");

    $index = 0;
    $kalender = array();

    while ( $dsatz = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $kalender[$index] = $dsatz;
        $index++;
    }

    function encode_items(&$item, $key) // Umlaute behandeln
    {
        $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($kalender, 'encode_items');

    print json_encode( $kalender );

    mysqli_close( $db );?>
```

...and here the connect.php

```
    <?php
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "webXXX";
        $password = "moby";
        $database= "dick";

        $db = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $password, $database ) or die(mysqli_error());

        $db->select_db("termine");
    ?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf-8');` is mysql and you seem to be using `mysqli`

Comment: as above, the second query is fine, the 1st one is generating the error

Comment: thanks a lot! mysqli( $db, 'SET NAMES utf-8' ) fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `connect.php` with

```
<?php
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "webXXX";
        $password = "moby";
        $database= "dick";

        $db = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $password, $database ) or die(mysqli_error());


    ?>
```

You are selecting a database you have not authenticated. In your `$db` variable you already selected your database so no need using `$db->select_db("termine")` as you have not authenticated db `termine` this will throw an error. Instead if you still want to use the `select_db` method do it like this `$db->select_db($database)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: [Did you read the comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182038/access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no-but-data-delivered#comment52250195_32182038)